# How to specify Composer install path?

Tags: php, symfony1, composer-php

I have this definition:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "symfony/sfGuardPlugin",
                "version": "4.0.2",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://plugins.symfony-project.org/get/sfGuardPlugin/sfGuardPlugin-4.0.2.tgz",
                    "type": "tar"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "symfony/sfGuardPlugin": "4.0.*"
    }
}
```

I am using Symfony 1, and I'd like to install them on `plugins/sfGuardPlugin/`. How do I specify this?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

It seems that you can define the `vendor` dir to be [something else](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir) (`plugins` in your case):

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "plugins"
    }
}
```

Then, you might rename the package name to not have a level dir inside, like:

```
        "package": {
            "name": "sfGuardPlugin",
```

So, your `composer.json` should look like this:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "plugins"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "sfGuardPlugin",
                "version": "4.0.2",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://plugins.symfony-project.org/get/sfGuardPlugin/sfGuardPlugin-4.0.2.tgz",
                    "type": "tar"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "sfGuardPlugin": "4.0.*"
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Using this configuration, you will get the path (which is *of course* not good for symfony):

> plugins/sfGuardPlugin/sfGuardPlugin-4.0.2/

I found a workaround with this `composer.json`:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "plugins"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "sfGuardPlugin",
                "version": "4.0.2",
                "source": {
                    "url": "http://svn.symfony-project.com/plugins/sfGuardPlugin/",
                    "type": "svn",
                    "reference": "branches/1.3/"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "sfGuardPlugin": "4.0.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, also can I somehow make it so that the extracted folder does not go as deep as it does now: `plugins/sfGuardPlugin/sfGuardPlugin-4.0.2/`, instead I want `plugins/sfGuardPlugin`?

Comment: Yeah, just saw that. I'm trying with a different type (instead of `tar`).

Comment: That works well -- so they still have a repository after all :)

Comment: yep :) and I don't think it will be removed in the far far future.

Comment: is there a way to specify the vendor dir for some specific package only, and leave the others as default?

Comment: This is a great and researched answer, but don't loose Adam's V., because it seems more official, oh and easy ;-)

Answer (score 28):

You can also use [composer/installers](http://composer.github.com/installers/), a multi-framework composer library installer with the "symfony1-plugin" package type. This is what my composer.json file looks like, in order for it to install both Symfony 1.4 (in lib/vendor) and plugins in (/plugins):

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "lib/vendor"
    },
    "repositories": {
        "symfony": {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "symfony/symfony1",
                "version": "1.4",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/zipball/1.4",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        },
        "sfResquePlugin" : {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "devpips/sfResquePlugin",
                "type": "symfony1-plugin",
                "version": "0.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/devpips/sfResquePlugin/zipball/master",
                    "type": "zip"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "dev-master",
        "symfony/symfony1": "1.4",
        "devpips/sfResquePlugin":"0.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would point anything to `/plugins` - can you elaborate?

Comment: @IsaacLubow, this will be done by `composer-installers` package, as `symfony1` have a plugin there :) Check [Symfony1Installer.php](https://github.com/composer/installers/blob/master/src/Composer/Installers/Symfony1Installer.php)

Answer (score 15):

See [`COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-vendor-dir) environment variable.

> By setting this var you can make Composer install the dependencies into a directory other than vendor.

Can be helpful in the case you want to override this in a particular environment such as vagrant or docker where you wouldn't want this to be in a shared folder / volume.

And as J0k said, there's [`vendor-dir`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir) in `config` section of `composer.json`

> Defaults to vendor. You can install dependencies into a different directory if you want to. $HOME and ~ will be replaced by your home directory's path in vendor-dir and all *-dir options below.