# Let Composer to install plugins to another directory

Tags: composer-php

I have framework wich uses plugins as subdirectories in `plugin/` directory. Plugins are git submodules and it works just fine. But some plugins require 3rd party libraries and I want to use Composer ti install them. Also there are dependencies between plugins which could be handled by Composer too.

I tried to use composer, but it will install everything into `vendor/` directory, which is wrong because plugins must go into `plugin/` directory. There is also core of the framework in `core/` and application specific files in `app/` directory.

What is the best way to use Composer in this scenario?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify Composer install path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path)

Comment: Looks like duplicate, but without satisfying answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There should be a way for Composer to decide which package is a plugin and should be placed in the plugins directory. In composer, there is a special [type](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type) setting which you should use in that case.

Then you can use a [custom installer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/custom-installers.md) to install the special plugin types in the plugin directory.

Comment: Do you have a working example of this, please? There is too many holes in that documentation.

Comment: @JosefKufner the docs give you phpdocumentor as an example, you can look at that