# Composer, move files from /vendor/ folder

Tags: php, composer-php, phpstorm

I've just started using composer with PHPStorm 'cause I'm bored of downloading dependencies from github manually. But there are some things I can't understand.

Composer always downloads files into **/vendor** folder. Like if I add Twitter Bootstrap - it will be downloaded to **/vendor/twitter/bootstrap** folder. But I need it to be into my **/webroot/bootstrap/** directory. How do you move this files? Because if I move it manually - they won't be updated later using composer update command.

Or if I use micro php framevork slim. I've added **slim/slim** dependency. But it will be placed into **/vendor/slim/slim/...**

So what should I do? Use Phing or some other deployment tool to move files from /vendor to desired destination? What do you use?

That's not exactly whar I need, but it works for css/js/etc.
http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/8429/post/1-Using-Composer-to-Install-JavaScript-CSS-and-Images-Under-the-Web-Document-Directory.html

Comment: You can simply `require vendor/autoload.php;` and then it doesn't really matter *where* the directory is.

Comment: What's wrong with Slim being in the vendors folder? For webroot resources, I'm using [`bower`](http://bower.io) instead of `composer` for that, or you could symlink the files into the webroot directory.

Comment: @Jack, autoloading works only for php classes. That's ok. But with static like images/css/js.

Comment: @deceze, symlink looks good, but I develop under windows. Not a goot choice, I know. Here I'm looking for a best practice. What is the common way of using composer. You've suggest symlink - thank you, I think that's a good choice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify Composer install path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path)

Comment: @Jack, not exactly. I'm looking for a best practice, 'cause I'm not used to composer. If moving files is bad - ok, I want to know a right way to develop.

Comment: @Alexey, you'll want to keep your code separated from 3rd party code (such as the Slim framework). The easiest way is to use the `vendor` map for that and a `src` map for your own code. Of course javascript and css need to be web-accessible.

Comment: @Arjan, I'm sorry, but I don't understand. Maybe 'cause lack of english. What do you mean by vendor and src map? Mapping where and how it should help me separate my code from 3rd party one?

Comment: @Alexey: My bad. I should have used folder instead of map. Composer uses `<project root>/vendor/` for 3rd party code and you could use `<project root>/src` for your source code. That way you keep them separated.

Answer (score 31):

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "path/to/wherever"
},
```

in your composer.json file

Comment: This saved me! Using Netbeans composer is in root as vendor is. But if you, like me, created folder eg. `code` just for code part of project that will be eventually rsync-ed to production server, with this config I have moved vendor inside code subdir `code/vendor/` keeping composer in root of nb project.

Comment: Unfortunately Class mapping is unable to change per ENV (dev, production). In local have code, but don't have on production.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md) states that you can do this:

```
{
    "extra": {
        "installer-paths": {
            "sites/example.com/modules/{$name}": ["vendor/package"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yupp! Thank you. But this works only for packages using composer/installers.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path).

Vendor directory is a Composer convention. Good programming practice is to prefer convention over configuration. You can reference you files and classes in a number of ways with Composer.

Comment: I don't believe that the OP's question is answered here or in the question you refer to. I think the OP has some vendor files that should pref be outside of the web root and others (like bootstrap, angular etc) that obviously needs to be under the web root - so two vendor destinations for one project

Comment: As JannieT said. This is not the answer to the original question. Also the hint is correct.