# Tidying up folder structure for libraries added with composer

Tags: configuration, composer-php, silverstripe

Starting with a default installation of SilverStripe (using composer), I have the folders *framework*, *cms*, *mysite*, etc.

Using composer I then added some additional code, such as userforms with the command:

```
composer require silverstripe/userforms
```

This created the folder *userforms* in the root of my site.

However, to manage my code more easily, it would be nicer if all modules added by composer were in a subfolder together. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23547863/612253) indicates how a default vendor-dir directory can be specified using the composer.json file.

There is already a *vendor* folder in existence (if I understand correctly, this is used by composer). Is it ok to use the *vendor* folder as the default vendor-dir setting, or would it be better to create a new folder instead?

Also, what do I need to do to move existing folders (such as *userforms*) into the appropriate sub-folder?

Comment: I wonder if manifest builder ignores *vendor/* folder or not...

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is specified by [type](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type). The packages with `"type": "library"` will be placed into `vendor` folder.

This is how the framework was designed, it expects the files to be located where they are now. It uses legacy code and is unable to make use of Composer autoloading.