# Handling Symfony2 project and Git branching

Tags: git, symfony, composer-php, phpstorm, git-branch

I have a project in Symfony2 which maintains several branches in Git: `develop`, `testing` and some other. The file `composer.json` is different on each branch so I need to run `composer update` all the time to update dependencies and/or delete old or new libraries which might cause unwanted behavior.

Right now I am learning and trying to write some tests using BDD: Behat + Mink and I don't want to have that changes on `develop` branch so I have created `testing` and made all those changes on that branch but as I said the main problem is to run `composer update` any time I switch branches.

Which is the right way to handle this? How would you do it? Any advice? I am getting crazy running the same command several times and then synchronizing my local code (Windows host) on PHPStorm against remote code (Linux server). Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few different things come to mind. Some are more best practices, others may alleviate turnaround time, depending on how much effort you want to exert:

Basic:

- **On .lock down** - Make sure each branch has a committed lock file. There's a reason its [right in the Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file). Too few projects seem to appreciate SemVer, and even those can let a breaking change sneak in from time to time.
- **Be Specific** When running a composer update, make sure you're targeting the *specific* packages that differ between branches (ex: `composer update doctrine/dbal`).

  - Better yet, don't run `update` at all. This could be erroneously updating a package in a branch you hadn't intended to. Better to utilize `composer install`.
- **Why not both?** - Might it also be worthwhile to just have a separate clone of your project dedicated to that branch? If you see yourself regularly working in both, spare the entire headache of toggling branches. After all, disk space is cheap.

  - Delete all branches from local except for the ones you're interested in. Setup Git Push/Pull to 'Simple' to avoid any accidental commits.

Moderate or Higher

- **Be lazy, go have some coffee** - Consider a post-checkout hook. You can see [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#composer-lock-the-lock-file) for an example. Enjoy the spare cycles to grab some coffee, map our your next test.
- **Roll Your Own** - Install a local [Satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) instance. I've noticed a marked improvement in our project installs after our team added a local Satis instance w/ mirroring of our primary dependencies.
- **VM** - Transition your project to use a VM. GUI-based tools such as [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/) or [Phansible](http://phansible.com/) can ease you in to things. This won't solve your composer problem, but cutting down on the roundtrip with the remote for sync will likely be worth the time investment.
- **Config tweak** - Change composer's vendor dir on a per-branch basis. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11883676/4375304) for details.

  - Note: This has a high probability of adding some complications to your testing due to unexpected/branch-specific permissions errors, etc.
- **Platform.sh**:

  1. Set up an account with Platform.sh
  2. [???](http://symfony.com/blog/how-we-auto-deploy-documentation-pull-requests-with-platform-sh)
  3. Profit

Hopefully some combination of the above will help you find some improvements!