# Different folders for app/bootstrap/vendor in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel

Currently I use this structure:

```
app/
bootstrap/
vendor/
public/
```

I would like to change it to

```
app-2/
bootstrap-2/
vendor-2/
public/
```

How to do that, I mean, which files do I need to change the path?

RIght now I have tried to change paths in:

public/index.php

then in:

bootstrap/autoload.php

bootstrap/path.php

bootstrap/start.php

Basically I have changed every /app/ to /app-2/ and the same for bootstrap and vendor.

But for some reason, the controllers from to app/controllers are executed instead of app-2/controllers

Any idea, if I am missing some file that needs to be edited also?

IN the debugger I see vendor-2, so that's correct, but why are loaded controllers from app instead of app-2 folder?

Comment: This is unlikely to work. At all.

Comment: It has to work, why not? Why not to hardcode the paths then?

Comment: That's stupid if it's not possible. Is this fixed in Laravel 5? Or still not? What about Lumen? Are you able to define your own names for app,bootstrap and vendor folders there?

Comment: Lumen is Laravel-based, so it will be similarly difficult there. What are you trying to *accomplish* with this?

Comment: I have multiple versions of the same project and A/B testing different configurations/environments. But man... this is like a shot in the heart. Why is it like this? I don't get it. Maybe I will end up with PhalconPHP after all ;(

Comment: That's a bit of a weird way of handling versions and A/B testing. You'd typically just deploy different branches of the app to two different locations on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Change the app directory

To accomplish this, you'd need to update your `composer.json` file, since that is the one that ultimately determines how Laravel's autoloader behaves.

You should see a section similar to this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

change it to:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app-2/"
    }
},
```

That change will mean that when the autoloader comes across any class in the `App` namespace, it will try to load it from the `app-2` directory. After making this change, you'll need to run the following CLI command to regenerate the autoloader's PHP files:

```
php composer.phar dump-autoload
```

That command may be slightly different depending on how you installed composer on your system.

### Change the vendor directory

You can also change the install path of composer's packages from `vendor` to `vendor-2` by [adding another config option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path) into `composer.json`.

### Change the bootstrap directory

You'll need to update references to the bootstrap directory in the following files:

```
./public/index.php
./artisan
```

Comment: thanks, it's a little bit complicated. It's a shame that it can't be changed easier. Do you know if CodeIgniter or some other framework can do it like I want.

Comment: To be honest, what you're trying to do is very hacky and I wouldn't recommend it. I just provided the answer to your question without opinion. 
If you explain what exactly you're doing this for, I may be able to help further with a cleaner solution