# Add directory using Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I wanted to get several Git repositories then place it on a certain directory on my Git-tracked project. My current project structure:

```
- custom
- plugins
- file.txt
```

When the user do a `composer install`, I wanted it to fetch this [Git repo](https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-nginx) then place it under new directory on my project named *provisioning*.

```
- custom
- plugins
- provisioning
  - nginx
- file.txt
```

Am I using the Composer the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the composer will install dependencies to vendor directory. If you need to install everything into directory names provisioning the use

```
"config": {
    "vendor-dir": "plugins"
},
```

in your composer.json file and then run `composer install command`

Further details in [How to specify Composer install path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path)