# Composer install to target folder

Tags: php, composer-php

I am using Composer v1.10.6 and am trying to get the dependencies to install into a specific folder.  File structure is like this:

```
/some-folder
composer.json
composer.lock
```

So I want the dependencies defined in `composer.json` to be installed under `/some-folder/vendor`, but they are just getting installed to `/vendor`. What property do I add to `composer.json` to make this happen?  I see there used to be a `target-dir` property, but it is deprecated.

I want to do this in `composer.json` so I can install dependencies just with `composer install`, not something like `composer install --dir=/some-folder`.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify Composer install path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883374/how-to-specify-composer-install-path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting [`config.vendor-dir`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir) in your `composer.json` like this:

```
{
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "some-folder"
    }
}
```