# Why does composer ignore the installer-paths in composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php

Due to an existing company policy, I have to  install packages in a directory other than the default `./vendor` but composer stubbornly continues to create the default `./vendor` directory and install everything there.

As per the [FAQ](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md), I have the following `composer.json` contents:

```
  "require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "*"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "3rdparty/": ["type:library"]
    }
  }
}
~
```

I expected this to install `monolog` under `./3rdparty` but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: *I am attempting to install packages in a directory other than the default `./vendor`* Why? It looks like it create more problems than it would solve.

Comment: @A.L I'm required to adhere to an existing company policy. That said, answers to the tune of "don't do that then" aren't really helpful. If I didn't have to muck around with this, I wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it, it wasn't mentioned in the question. I wanted to ensure that it wasn't an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/237701).

Comment: it's config vendor-dir or COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR and has nothing to do with installers, this is standard composer configuration. https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir / https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-vendor-dir

Comment: @hakre please add this as answer.

Comment: @A.L: The answer exists already, no need to add it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11883676/367456 and related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the list of packages that can use this option is limited, there is a note at the bottom of this FAQ page :

> Note: You cannot use this to change the path of any package. This is only applicable to packages that require composer/installers and use a custom type that it handles.

Maybe [this repository](https://github.com/mnsami/composer-custom-directory-installer) will do the trick ?